# Find the longest streak without using built in functions

Tags: python

I have a list like `Y Y Y N Y`. I need to figure out the longest streak. The code

```py
print(max(map(len,input().replace(' ','').split('N'))))
```

works but I need to do this without `max` and `split`.

The following code works for `Y Y Y N` and for `N N N` (results zero) but fails for `Y Y N Y Y Y`.
I need to somehow introduce a counter that is not set to 0 after the streak is broken and remember the largest streak

```py
Y = 'Y'
temp = 0
streak = False

entry = input()
mylist = list(entry)

for i in range(0, len(mylist)):
    if mylist[i] == Y:
        streak = True
        temp = temp + 1              
    else:
        streak = False
        #print (temp)
        #temp = 0
print(temp)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: How can you write _anything_ without built in functions?

Comment: You are using `input`, `list`, `range` , `len` and `print` which are all built-in functions. What's the purpose of the non built-in restriction?

Comment: Anyway all you're missing is to reset the counter (`temp`) and check if it's greater than the current maximum (which you are missing) in the `else` part. The boolean `streak` variable is really unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

I codded the general case of unknown input (not only N and Y), and without using built-in functions `max` or `split` by building an histogram and find out the maximum in it (take into calculation the case of several times the same letter as input), e.g:

input: `insert string: yyttyyyy`

```
entry = input("insert string: ")
mylist = list(entry)
hist = {} # string as key and int as value
lastItem = None
iterations_num = 0
for item in mylist:
    if item == lastItem:
        if item + str(iterations_num) in hist.keys():
            hist[item + str(iterations_num)] = hist[item + str(iterations_num)]+1
    else:
        lastItem = item
        iterations_num = iterations_num+1
        hist[item + str(iterations_num)] = 1
max = 0
for amount in hist.values():
    if amount>max:
        max = amount
print(hist)
print(max)
```

output:

```
{'y1': 2, 't2': 2, 'y3': 4}
4
```

Answer (score 0):

All you're missing is to reset the counter (`temp`) and check if it's greater than the current maximum (which you are missing) in the `else` part. The boolean `streak` variable is really unnecessary:

```py
longest = 0
streak = 0

entry = input()
mylist = entry.split()

for elem in mylist:
    if elem == 'Y':
        streak += 1
    else:
        longest = max(longest, streak)
        streak = 0

print(max(longest, streak))
```